# Why is jQuery deleting my <img> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery with the BlockUI plugin to block a page after a link is clicked. I'm also using a DOM element to display a message when the page is blocked.

Here's a simple example of the code used:

```
<a id="testme" href="#">Click Me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#testme').click(function() {
            // Set our message in the message panel....
            $('#progressMessage').text('Please wait!');
            $.blockUI({
                message: $('#progressWidget')
            });
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="progressWidget" style="display:none" align="center">
    <div class="modalUpdateProgressMessage">
        <div id="progressMessage" />
        <img src="spinbar.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I set the `.text()` of the `<div id="progressMessage" />` element, the `<img src="spinbar.gif" />` element seems to get removed. I've verified that this is actually happening using Firebug.

I've also tried using a `<span>` instead of a `<div>` for `progressMessage` but the result is the same.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do a self-closing DIV, it's not valid.

Comment: I missed that... I thought the image was in the #progressMessage div.

Answer (score 2):

The self closing  is the problem

```
$("#selector").append("<div>"); //fail

$("#selector").append("<div/>"); //fail

$("#selector").append("<div></div>"); //SUCCESS!
```

Comment: In the second one: $("#selector").append("<div/>"); is that a bug or by design? I'm thinking that <div /> is valid XHTML ?

Answer (score 1):

The div id="progressMessage" overwrites the img when it is assigned a text.
use `<div id="progressMessage"></div>` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use .append to add the text

```
$('#progressMessage').text('Please wait!');
```

[.append()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content)